# Maintain line breaks with cell when assigning value to html table

Tags: html, excel, email, html-email, vba

I am generating a html email which contains a table of certain values from an excel worksheet based on flag values. The problem I'm having is that some cells contain line break in them, for example:

In cell B5, a user has entered:

```
Red
Blue
Green
```

With a line space between each word.

I am using

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Cells(5,2).Value</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

this returns:

`red blue green`

in one row within the table cell. What I want is the text wrapped over 3 rows within the one table cell:

```
red
blue
green
```

Other cells in the same row might only contain a single value so adding extra rows isn't really the solution I'm after.

How do i retain the line breaks that were initially entered into the cell when assigning the value to the html table in an email?

Answer (score 0):

HTML needs `BR` elements to markup line breaks. So you need replacing the `\n` `Chr(10)` line breaks with `<br/>`.

Like so:

```
sHTML = "<html><table><tr><td>"
sHTML = sHTML & Replace(Cells(5, 2).Value, Chr(10), "<br/>")
sHTML = sHTML & "</td></tr></table></html>"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works a treat!